# The user specified as a definer does not exist

Tags: mysql, database

I get the following error after importing my database's backup into an already existing website:

> *The user specified as a definer ('someuser'@'%') does not exist*

I am already logged into my database, and when I execute

```
SHOW PRIVILEGES;
```

I can see that I am allowed

> *"To give to other users those privileges you posses..."*

Consequently, I execute

```
CREATE USER 'someuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

but I get the following error:

> *#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation*

I also tried the

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

alternative, but got the following response:

> *#1045 - Access denied for user 'anotheruser'@'%' (using password: YES)*

Please someone help me out with this! I've read into another similar posts but those answers didn't work for me since I got the above specified responses.

Answer (score 3):

The definer that cause the creation script to failed is related to stored procedures/functions, events and triggers.

[image]

One way to work around your problem would be to search and replace all the instances, in the script, of your non-existing user by your own user.

Comment: Mil gracias, me salvo, no encontraba la falla.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonathan said, definer is usually related to functions/triggers definitions.

Now regarding your first error, you need to define `'someuser'@'%'` before the import. This is different than `'someuser'@'localhost'`.

regarding `#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation`, it means your mysql user does not have this privilege.

You need to login with root, or give current user CREATE USER privilege(s).